# Short Solution to Sort a C++ Vector of Objects with Dependencies to Each Other?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, std

I just wrote part of a software where fields are ordered in the correct way for processing. Each field can depend on 0-n other fields. Loops are already checked and prevented in a previous step.

My current code works, but it is not very elegant. I iterate through the list and move dependent entries to the front, until there is no move required.

Here a minimal example illustrating the problem:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Obj {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> dependencies;
};

std::vector<Obj*> objects;

void printObjList(std::string title) {
    std::cout << title << std::endl;
    for (auto obj : objects) {
        std::cout << "- " << obj->name << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    objects.push_back(new Obj {"d", {}});
    objects.push_back(new Obj {"a", {"c", "d"}});
    objects.push_back(new Obj {"b", {}});
    objects.push_back(new Obj {"c", {"e", "d"}});
    objects.push_back(new Obj {"e", {"b"}});
    printObjList("Unsorted");
    std::stable_sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](Obj *a, Obj *b) {
        return a->name < b->name;
    });
    //std::stable_sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](Obj *a, Obj *b) {
        // ???
    //});
    printObjList("Sorted by Dependencies");
    return 0;
}
```

Play with the code here:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/902e91b00924a925

An object which is part of `dependencies` in another object has to be sorted **before** this object which contains the reference in the `dependencies` list.

I assume there is some well known algorithm to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Hi, I think what you are looking for is algorithms for the Topological Sorting problem: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting
e.g. Kahn's algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my quick comment:

If you have already checked that there are no loops in your items, then what you have is a  directed acyclic graph (DAG).

Sorting that is the problem known as Topological sorting:
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) which has known efficient solutions, like Kahn's algorithm, though to take advantage of it's efficiency, you'll have to be careful how you store your nodes and edges, so that some operations (for example, finding a node with no incoming edges) is efficient (constant time)

Some well known libraries, like boost also provide implementations:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html

Comment: Perfect, this solved the problem. I used a simple depth-first algorithm as shown here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c0bf8d3443b804d You may add this to illustrate your answer.